# What's the closest I can get to calling a Python function using a different Python version?

Tags: python, compatibility, popen

Say I have two files:

```
# spam.py
import library_Python3_only as l3

def spam(x,y)
    return l3.bar(x).baz(y)
```

and

```
# beans.py
import library_Python2_only as l2

...
```

Now suppose I wish to call `spam` from within `beans`. It's not directly possible since both files depend on incompatible Python versions. Of course I can `Popen` a different python process, but how could I pass in the arguments and retrieve the results without too much stream-parsing pain?

Comment: Is your function in backports?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a complete example implementation using `subprocess` and `pickle` that I actually tested. Note that you need to use protocol version 2 explicitly for pickling on the Python 3 side (at least for the combo Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.3).

```
# py3bridge.py

import sys
import pickle
import importlib
import io
import traceback
import subprocess

class Py3Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, mod_name, func_name):
        self.mod_name = mod_name
        self.func_name = func_name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-m', 'py3bridge',
                              self.mod_name, self.func_name],
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, _ = p.communicate(pickle.dumps((args, kwargs)))
        data = pickle.loads(stdout)
        if data['success']:
            return data['result']
        else:
            raise Exception(data['stacktrace'])

def main():
    try:
        target_module = sys.argv[1]
        target_function = sys.argv[2]
        args, kwargs = pickle.load(sys.stdin.buffer)
        mod = importlib.import_module(target_module)
        func = getattr(mod, target_function)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        data = dict(success=True, result=result)
    except Exception:
        st = io.StringIO()
        traceback.print_exc(file=st)
        data = dict(success=False, stacktrace=st.getvalue())

    pickle.dump(data, sys.stdout.buffer, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Python 3 module (using the `pathlib` module for the showcase)

```
# spam.py

import pathlib

def listdir(p):
    return [str(c) for c in pathlib.Path(p).iterdir()]
```

The Python 2 module using `spam.listdir`

```
# beans.py

import py3bridge

delegate = py3bridge.Py3Wrapper('spam', 'listdir')
py3result = delegate('.')
print py3result
```

Comment: Excellent. I ran into some issues with environment variables (the Python2 environment is a local install embedded into another program, which overrides `PATH` etc.), but this could be fixed by replacing the direct `python3` Popen call with `[ 'env', '-i', 'bash', '-l', '-c', 'python3 -m py3bridge '+self.mod_name+' '+self.func_name ]`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There is also the `env` parameter of `subprocess.Popen` where you can pass the environment variables for the child process.

Comment: Ah, but can that also be used to simply ignore given parameters / revert to the login defaults?

Comment: I don't know about login default, but you could do something like `env = dict(os.environ)`, `del env['HAZARDOUS_VAR']`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the caller is Python3.5+, you have access to a nicer [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Perhaps you could user `subprocess.run`, and communicate via pickled Python objects sent through stdin and stdout, respectively. There would be some setup to do, but no parsing on your side, or mucking with strings etc.

Here's an example of Python2 code via subprocess.Popen

```
p = subprocess.Popen(python3_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(pickle.dumps(python3_args))
result = pickle.load(stdout)
```

Comment: Actually I wrote the versions the wrong way around in my example: I really hope to call python3 from python2. Anyway I hoped that this didn't really make the difference... surely pickling also works that direction? If not, an answer that only works if the caller is Python3 would also be helpful (perhaps I can in fact turn around the dependence).

Comment: The option of using pickled objects still stands, it will just be harder to setup the stdin and read the stdout of the child process, as you have to use subprocess.call or subprocess.Popen, which have a clunkier interface. You still avoid having do do manual parsing, since the meat of the problem will still be a call to pickle.dumps/loads, it's just a little bit more code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module was added in Python 2.4, so there doesn't seem to be a reason why you can't use it in your case.

Comment: @ray Yes, the subprocess module is there, but it doesn't have the nicer 'run' method. I've added an example with 'Popen', and it's not that bad either. Just needs some exception handling thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple script as such :

```
import sys
import my_wrapped_module
import json

params = sys.argv
script = params.pop(0)
function = params.pop(0)
print(json.dumps(getattr(my_wrapped_module, function)(*params)))
```

You'll be able to call it like that :

```
pythonx.x wrapper.py myfunction param1 param2
```

This is obviously a security hazard though, be careful.

Also note that if your params are anything else than string or integers, you'll have some issues, so maybe think about transmitting params as a json string, and convert it using `json.loads()` in the wrapper.

Comment: Looks not bad. However I don't suppose this is suitable when the parameters contain a lot of data? For the application I have in mind right now, it might be ok, but generally I'd feel uncomfortable passing such large json-encoded strings through the command line.

Comment: I'd feel uncomfortable using this myself! haha. Maybe it can help, but the best solution would probably be to use `2to3` to convert your python2 libraries.

Comment: I'd definitely rather migrate everything to Python3, but that's not really an option since that particular Python2 engine is a modified version that's embedded in a third-party C++ project.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the [`multiprocessing.managers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) module to achieve what you want. It does require a small amount of hacking though.

Given a module that has functions you want to expose then you need to create a `Manager` that can create proxies for those functions.

manager process that serves proxies to the py3 functions:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import spam

class SpamManager(BaseManager):
    pass
# Register a way of getting the spam module.
# You can use the exposed arg to control what is exposed.
# By default only "public" functions (without a leading underscore) are exposed,
# but can only ever expose functions or methods.
SpamManager.register("get_spam", callable=(lambda: spam), exposed=["add", "sub"])

# specifying the address as localhost means the manager is only visible to  
# processes on this machine
manager = SpamManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abc', 
    serializer='xmlrpclib')
server = manager.get_server()
server.serve_forever()
```

I've redefined `spam` to contain two function called `add` and `sub`.

```
# spam.py
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sub(x, y):
    return x - y
```

client process that uses the py3 functions exposed by the `SpamManager`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class SpamManager(BaseManager):
    pass
SpamManager.register("get_spam")

m = SpamManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey=b'abc', 
    serializer='xmlrpclib')
m.connect()

spam = m.get_spam()
print("1 + 2 = ", spam.add(1, 2)) # prints 1 + 2 = 3
print("1 - 2 = ", spam.sub(1, 2)) # prints 1 - 2 = -1
spam.__name__ # Attribute Error -- spam is a module, but its __name__ attribute 
# is not exposed
```

Once set up, this form gives an easy way of accessing functions and values. It also allows these functions and values to be used them in a similar way that you might use them if they were not proxies. Finally, it allows you to set a password on the server process so that only authorised processes can access the manager. That the manager is long running, also means that a new process doesn't have to be started for each function call you make.

One limitation is that I've used the `xmlrpclib` module rather than `pickle` to send data back and forth between the server and the client. This is because python2 and python3 use different protocols for `pickle`. You could fix this by adding your own client to `multiprocessing.managers.listener_client` that uses an agreed upon protocol for pickling objects.